# how to replace filename with value of variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a variable:

```
    public static string ClientName;
```

And the code below which saves an image to a folder on server:

```
 public static void UploadPic(string imageData)
{

    string Pic_Path = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "SavedSig/ClientSignature.png");
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Pic_Path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to rename that file everytime with the value of the variable instead of the static ClientSignature.png"

Comment: why not `tring Pic_Path = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, ClientName);`?

Comment: @Grundy I would put that as an answer as it is what he is looking for :)

Comment: What's the big in replacing the static value with a variable? It's a simple programming.

Comment: received with thanks, i have tried that but i would want it to still be a .png image eg if the variable is 1 then the image would be 1.png and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line

```
string Pic_Path = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath,
    "SavedSig/ClientSignature.png");
```

into the following, which uses [string concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx) to create the final string

```
string Pic_Path = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath,
    string.Format("SavedSig/{0}.png", ClientName));
```

Comment: received with thanks, i have tried that but i would want it to still be a .png image eg if the variable is 1 then the image would be 1.png and so on

Comment: your string would be better as `string.Format("SavedSig/{0}.png", ClientName)`

Comment: @Sayse Indeed it would. I changed it.